# XMLHttpRequest cannot load, but the Response show 200 status

Tags: json, api, http, cors, httpresponse

There is an API which I'm trying to parse.

It's JSON response but I'm facing this error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load:example.com/api/e.json`.

**Note:** After searching for this error I understood that i can't do it because the server must set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header` to `*` but i'm still getting the json response which I need at **the network section on browser inspector with 200 status** but it doesn't work if I try to parse it to my page.

I want to know is it possible to parse this response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

The way CORS works in browsers is, even when your browser gets the response successfully—and you can see it in devtools—the browser checks the response before exposing it to your client-side JavaScript code—to decide whether or not to expose it to your code.

And if the browser finds the response either doesn’t contain the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, or the value of that doesn’t allow the origin your client-side code is running at, then the browser won’t expose the response to your code. Instead the browser will emit a message saying the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing or doesn’t allow your origin.